# Is there anyway to improve performance of this code?

Tags: android, sqlite, webview, android-sqlite

My first app. I am implementing search functionality in it.

I have done this so far.

DB part:

```
String sqlStr = "SELECT Book_Name, PlainEng_Text, PlainArab_Text,  REF, Had_Number, Book_Number, Collection_ID FROM Had_Table WHERE Collection_ID = 1 AND ID IN " +
                "(SELECT ID FROM Had_Virtual_Table WHERE Hadith_Virtual_Table MATCH ?)";

        //String[] selectionArgs = { QueryString };

        curHadlist = dbHandle.rawQuery(sqlStr, QueryString);
```

This seems to work fine by returning records quick.
On one of my tests it returned more than 7100 records.

The below code is, I think, causing issues:

```
       while (curHadlist.moveToNext()) {
            curHTags.moveToFirst();
            String HTags = curHTags.getString(0);

            String BookN = curHadlist.getString(0);

            if (activityID == 2) {
                AB.setSubtitle(BookN);
            }

            String EngH = curHadlist.getString(1);
            String ArH = curHadlist.getString(2);
            String RefH = curHadlist.getString(3);
            String HadNum = curHadlist.getString(4);
            Integer BookNum = curHadlist.getInt(5);
            Integer CollectNum = curHadlist.getInt(6);

            hadlist = hadlist + String.format(HTags, HadNum, activityID, BookNum, CollectNum, EngH, ArH, RefH); //2=ID of this activity
        }
```

After this loop, I return `hadlist` and then use it here like this:

```
webViewF.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", hadlist , "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

**ISSUE:** My app, after entering search string(one which returned 7100+ records and likes of it), goes black and never comes back(waited for few minutes).

Can anyone please suggest better way to do what I am trying to achieve here.

Thank you.

Comment: Use method tracing or `Log` statements to determine exactly where you are spending your time. Massive string concatenation, as you are doing, will generate a lot of garbage, so GC collection time is part of this. But you may find that the issue is in `WebView` loading this large page. The "better way" would be to use `RecyclerView`, or `ListView`, or something instead of `WebView`, most likely.

Comment: For instance, you could **index** your search and your JOIN fields (if any). I got an average of **350x faster** results. And do the data retrieval in an AsyncTask, for instance. So not to have your UI hang while querying.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, it has to be that `webview`. It does take time to load when I load normal(big) pages in this app.

This is the last functionality I am implementing in this app. So far everything I have done is `WebView`. I don't want to change all of it to other options that you mentioned. 

I went with `WebView` because my initial data was HTML/CSS pages. And I thought it was easier way to start app development as CSS/HTML/JS is easier for me to change anything on page.

Thank you for your response, @CommonsWare

Comment: @ModularSynth thank you for your suggestion. I will do that on new thread. 
My DB Query is fast enough. It is the `WebView` that is causing issue.